# DateTime formatting confusion in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, jodatime

So I have the following data in a .csv file (this is only the first few rows) -

```
time                  temp
2015-08-14 00:00:05   30.00
2015-08-14 00:00:15   31.25
2015-08-14 00:00:25   33.45
2015-08-14 00:00:35   34.76
2015-08-14 00:00:45   36.43
```

I then create the following case class  -

```
scala> case class Temps(time: org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat, temp: String)
```

I then aim to create an RDD by creating the parse function

```
scala> def parse(line: String) = {
       val data = line.split(',')
       val time = data(0).????
       val temp= data(1).toString
       Temps(time, temp)
       }
```

So my question is, what do I put where the ??? is above? I'm not entirely sure how to format the DateTime in this scenario.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, for your `Temps`'s `time` **type** should be: `org.joda.time.DateTime`, `DateTimeFormat` is a **factory** for creating `DateTimeFormatter`(this is used to format time).

Second, you can use `DateTimeFormatter.parseDateTime` to `parse` date `string` to `DateTime`

so this code maybe should like be:

```
 case class Temps(time: DateTime, temp: String)

 val dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss")
 def parse(line: String) = {
       val data = line.split(',')
       val time = dateTimeFormatter.parseDateTime(data(0))
       val temp= data(1).toString
       Temps(time, temp)
 }
```